# When was the British Flag Theorem discovered or proven?

Tags: mathematics, euclidean-geometry

The [British Flag Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem) is a fancy name for a law relating distances from the corners of a rectangle to an arbitrary point.

The wikipedia article is small and has no history section. Could not find it on google either. When was this theorem first discovered or proven, and by whom?

Comment: The Wikipedia article references [Lardner (1848), p.87](https://books.google.com/books?id=5INRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false) who does not call it that, and includes it on the list of "*some of the most useful and remarkable theorems which may be inferred from the second book*" [of Euclid's Elements], without any other credits.